# Looking up IP address of an area, town or State

Tags: ip-address, geolocation, geotargeting

How can I find the IP of a location? I know I can lookup an IP's physical location anywhere but what about looking up the IP's of a specific area.

Answer (score 2):

IP addresses are assigned in blocks to various owners and then typically leased out to yet others, who assign them variously to customers or locations, they are not assigned by geograpic location per se. There isn't really a way to determine what location has been assigned what IP address other than to get the IP address of the location, at least that I am aware of..

Comment: Several sites offer subscriptions to these updated "sets" of IP's for use with geolocation. Surely there is a way to find some sort of narrow down method for location or ISP, node or service area...

Comment: If you purchase one of the databases, you can view which location uses which IP address, but these locations change regularly so you will have to continue purchasing new databases to keep your data accurate. Again, the IP addresses are not assigned by geographic location.